# accessibility detected as not on in KIF

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, kif

I have turned on accessibility in iOS simulator and tried running my KIF test, but I constantly am getting the following error:

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The accessibility inspector must be enabled in order to run KIF tests. It can be turned on in the Settings app of the simulator by going to General -> Accessibility.'
```

I've double checked in the plist whether it is enabled through:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :AXInspectorEnabled"  ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.0/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Accessibility.plist
```

and it indicate that it is.

any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this by running the tests in applicationDidBecomeActive

Answer (score 0):

The code which tests for accessibility-inspector was failing for me too. I forked the KIF repo and fixed it here: https://github.com/mflint/KIF/tree/fix-accessibility-inspector-detection

Pull request here: https://github.com/square/KIF/pull/152